# Using VBO to change users passwords

Tags: users, views

I need a method of changing users passwords which doesn't require email, as such the best solution I can come up with is providing "manager" roles the ability to reset passwords. However we do not want to provide these users with "administer users" permission.

I am thinking the best way of doing this is a view which displays "my team" (uses a user reference on that managers direct reports.) and uses views bulk operations however I can not find anywhere documentation on how to reset users passwords.

Ideally the VBO action would allow managers to select members on their team and reset passwords to a string, then update the user in person.

Comment: There are no methods for setting user password in Rules, as I can see.You have to write your own action (see [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module) for this, but this strategy can be dangerous.

Comment: Can I do it programmatically? In VBO php?

Comment: You can create an action _programmatically_. VBO uses actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Userplus has an action which changes a users password, I was able to use the below:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */
function userplus_actions_action_info() {
  $actions = array(
    'userplus_change_password_action' => array(
      'type' => 'user',
      'description' => t('Change user\'s password'),
      'configurable' => TRUE,
      'hooks' => array(),
    ),
  );
  return $actions;
}

/**
 * Action to change a user's password
 */
function userplus_change_password_action_form($context) {
  _user_password_dynamic_validation();
  $form['pass'] = array(
    '#title' => t('New password'),
    '#type' => 'password_confirm',
    '#description' => t('Provide a password for the selected users in both fields.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 25,
  );

  return $form;
}

function userplus_change_password_action_submit($form, $form_state) {
  return array('pass' => $form_state['values']['pass']);
}

function userplus_change_password_action(&$user, $context) {
  user_save($user, array('pass' => $context['pass']));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method, for Drupal 7, is to create a rules action, and save it in the file MODULENAME.rules.inc. Change "MODULENAME" by your module name.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function MODULENAME_rules_action_info() {
 return array(
   'of_client_change_password' => array(
     'label' => t('Change user\'s password'),
     'parameter' => array(
       'account' => array(
         'type' => 'user',
         'label' => t('User'),
        ),
       'password' => array(
         'type' => 'text',
         'label' => t('Password'),
       ),
     ),
     'group' => t('MODULENAME'),
   ),
 );
}

function MODULENAME_change_password($account, $password) {
  // If we pass the password in the $edit array, it will be properly hashed
  $edit['pass'] = $password;
  user_save($account, $edit);
}
```